# How to pass an array of constructors

Tags: typescript

How is it possible to pass an array of functions that return object of some type. In another words - array of constructors?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
    constructor(name: string, systems: Array<Function>){
        this.system = new systems[0]();
    }
```

but I got an error `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.` and as I understand I should somehow let compiler know what type of objects that constructor returns but I don't know how.

Assuming **RJM**'s answer,  here is a bit extended example of what I mean:

```
interface System{
    name: string;
}
interface Component{
    blahblha: string;
}
class Doh implements Component{
    blahblha: string;
}
class Bar implements System{
    name: string = 'bar';
} 

class Blah implements System{
    name: string = 'foo';
}
class Foo {
    systems: Array<System>;
    constructor(bars: Array<()=>System>) {
        for (let i in bars){
            this.systems.push(new bars[i]()); // error: only a void functions can be called with the 'new' keyword.
        }
    }
}
var foo = new Foo([Blah]); // error: Argument of type 'typeof Blah[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(() => System[]'. Type 'typeof Blah[]' is not assignable to type '() => System'.
```

I want to ensure that `Foo.systems` will be populated only with instances of objects that implements System interface. So I should have error doing something like `new Foo([Doh]);` but I'm getting error even when passing `Blah`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to instantiate classes you will have to refer to it's constructor using the **new** keyword.

```js
function factory(constructors: { new (): System }[]) {
    let constructed = constructors.map(c => new c());
}

interface System {
    name: string;
}
class SomeClass implements System {
    name: string;
    constructor() { }
}

class SomeOtherClass implements System {
    name: string;
    constructor() { }
}

let a = factory([SomeClass, SomeClass, SomeClass, SomeOtherClass]);
```

The **factory** function will receive a list of constructors that can create something of that satisfies the **System** interface.

Calling the method with a class that does not implement System will result in the error you are receiving now.

```js
class AnotherClass {}
factory([AnotherClass]); // error
```

Structural typing works as well, so you don't have to implement the interface explicitly.

```js
class AnotherClass {
    name: string
}
factory([AnotherClass]);
```

To make the code a little bit cleaner you can move the interface described for the **constructors** parameter to an **interface** declaration.

```js
// an interface that describes classes that create instances that satisfy the System interface
interface CreatesSystem {
    new (): System
}

interface System {
    name: string;
}

function factory(constructors: CreatesSystem[]) {
    let constructed = constructors.map(c => new c());
}
```

Comment: be careful though, type checking for this kind of thing kinda starts breaking down when you start using generics. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you use a lambda, it seems to compile and run ok.

```
function constructor(name: string, systems: Array<() => void>){
    this.system = new systems[0]();
}
```

Comment: but what if I want restrict to functions that return object of some class. Not all functions. Seems like `Array< () => ClassName >` is not a right way for doing this